# Can TCriticalSection.Acquire be safely called more than one time by a thread?

Tags: android, ios, multithreading, macos, delphi

On Windows platform, TCriticalSection is implemented by calling the Windows API EnterCriticalSection/LeaveCriticalSection. Microsoft documentation explicitly says that after a thread has ownership of a critical section, it can make additional calls to EnterCriticalSection.

So far so good.

But what about the behavior under the other platforms Delphi supports such as OSX, iOS and Android?

Other platforms seems to make use of TMonitor. So the question could be rewritten against TMonitor.

Answer (score 5):

The implementation of TCriticalSection under other platforms than Windows simply uses TMonitor. So the answer to your question reduces to the behaviour of TMonitor.Enter. At least the documentation states that TMonitor.Enter is reentrant.

This part of the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.TMonitor.Enter) would mean a "yes" to your answer:

> Prohibits the access of all other threads but the calling one to the specified object.

The relevant code part of TMonitor is in TMonitor.TryEnter:

```
function TMonitor.TryEnter: Boolean;
begin
  if FOwningThread = GetCurrentThreadId then  // check for recursion
  begin
    ...
    Result := True;
  ...
```

Comment: Can TMonitor be trusted in XE5? Older Delphi versions exposed problems with TMonitor...

Comment: @Uwe Raabe I saw that TCriticalSection makes use of TMonitor, but I didn't found TMonitor documented in DocWiki/XE5. I edited my question to add TMonitor in it.

Comment: @whosrdaddy I don't care about old Delphi versions. I'm using XE5.

Comment: @fpiette: Hence my question, I want to know if TMonitor is fixed or not?

Comment: As I understand it, it is fixed on Windows at least. But I will likely never trust it.

Comment: @whosrdady so you have another question which deserve another Stackoverflow article by itself.

Comment: Eric Grange's article http://www.delphitools.info/2013/06/06/tmonitor-vs-trtlcriticalsection/ implies severe performance issues. I wouldn't touch it, personally.

Comment: @Andy_D - the fourth paragraph of that post reads: 'Edit 2013-08-24: looks like the issue discussed here should be resolved in XE5, cf Monitoring the Monitor by Allen Bauer.'

Comment: I have added the relevant documentation to my answer.